# Sage Math Numbers

Tags: sage

if I have a numbers,for ex 87.
How can I make it : 87= 8 and 7

Comment: `[int(x) for x in str(87)]`

Comment: In what language?

Comment: in sagemath for ex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
a, b = divmod(87, 10)
```

**divmod** divides 87 by 10, returning both quotient and remainder.

Does that solve your issue?